# Split String from SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, string, sql-server-2008

I want to split the Birthdate column in my database..

```
Returned String from database : dd/mm/yyyy
```

I want to get each value on a seperate strings,

```
date = dd
month = mm
year = yyyy
```

I've tried something like this.. but this dont always work because some date were only one character? ex. 4/5/2012

```
Birthdate.ToString.Substring(0, 2)
```

Comment: Is `Birthdate` a `String`? If it's a `String`, don't call `ToString` on it. If it's a `Date`, use its `Day` property instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively could you not convert the string coming back from the DB to a date? You could subsequently access each component part by using `Date.Month`, etc.

```vb
Dim mydate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("21/05/2012")

Console.WriteLine(mydate.Day)
Console.WriteLine(mydate.Month)

Console.WriteLine(mydate.Year)
```

Comment: Might want to use `ParseExact`, just to make sure the month and day don't get swapped...

Comment: This code worked! :) 

mybdate = Convert.ToDateTime(UserTbl.Rows(0).Item("Birthdate"))
cmb_Month.SelectedIndex = mybdate.Month

Answer (score 1):

(a) you shouldn't use regional formats like `4/5/2012` - is that April 5th or May 4th? If I can't tell, how can SQL Server?

(b) you don't really need to split anything if it is stored as a date (you are storing your dates as dates, and not strings, right)? So if you want to do this from SQL Server, you can say:

```sql
SELECT 
  [day]   = DAY(date_column), 
  [month] = MONTH(date_column),
  [year]  = YEAR(date_column)
FROM
(
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, date_column, 103)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT '04/05/2012'
    UNION ALL SELECT '4/5/2012'
  ) AS x(date_column)
) AS y;
```

Result:

```
day  month  year
---  -----  ----
4    5      2012
4    5      2012
```

If your column is `DATE` then you should just be able to say:

```sql
SELECT 
  date_column,
  [day]   = DAY(date_column), 
  [month] = MONTH(date_column),
  [year]  = YEAR(date_column)
FROM
  dbo.tablename;
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, but I used date as a datatype for my column Birthdate?

Comment: @TheOxblood: So it works; you shouldn't even have to convert anything. Again: what's the type of the variable `Birthdate`?

Comment: That's ok! Thanks for the inputs!